# Windows Forms Blazor application not working after deployment to another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, blazor

I try to test [Build a Windows Forms Blazor app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/windows-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and it's working correctly on my computer, but when I published it and moved it to another computer, it did not work and I get an error about `wwwroot` and ask for path in my old computer

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Users\hadi\Desktop\BlazorWinForms-main\wwwroot\

So I tried to modify the `HostPage` and make it a relative path but that is not working either ...

```
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    blazorWebView1.HostPage = path+"wwwroot\\index.html";
```

**Update 1:**

I fallow the same Microsoft docs example without modifying and things and I tried this method

1. Copy the debug folder to another PC

I got the same error asking about `wwwroot` so I create same folder in the location that the program looking for I got another error asking (ONLY IF USE VISUAL STUDIO 2022 not Preview version) about `obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\scopedcss\bundle` folder so I also copy it to the same location and after I test it gave me `0x80070002` error.

Then

2. I delete `[Project Name].staticwebassets.runtime.json` from debug folder and it also did not work and give me `0x80070002`

after that as @Jime suggested

3. I publish it as a folder and a single executable file and it also in both cases gives me `0x80070002` error

I did something wrong but I don't know what it is?
[source code](https://github.com/alaidi/WinFormsBlazor)

I'm using visual studio Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0
[image]

**Update 2:**

If install visual studio on a test machine (windows sandbox) the program executes without error so I think the problem is with the publishing process and not all `DLL` export correctly

Comment: I assume you have set the build action of the files inside `wwwroot` to `Copy if newer` (so the `wwwroot` folder and subfolders are created in the output directory). Leave the reference to the Root as `[BlazorWebView].HostPage = "wwwroot\\index.html";`. When you copy the build (what is contained in the `net6.0-windows` folder of your Project), exclude the `[Project Name].staticwebassets.runtime.json` file, since that's a static reference to the original Path. Or edit it to specify the new path (it must be an absolute path, folder names separated with `\\ `).

Comment: Note that you can also right-click the Project, select `Publish`, select `Folder` as publish destination (not `Azure` or `ClickOnce`, of course), change the output folder to `\bin\Publish`, click the Publish button on top of the applet. This will create a Release build and a `Publish` folder that contains all the files needed (you'll see that `[Project Name].staticwebassets.runtime.json` is not part of the published app).

Comment: As a secondary note, using the Publish applet, you can also configure it to generate a self-contained executable: click `Show all settings`; in the UI that opens up, set `Deployment mode` to `Self-contained`, `Target Runtime` to `win-x64`. Click `File publish options` and tick `Produce single file` and, optionally, `Enable ReadyToRun Compilation` -- In the Publish folder, you need the executable, the `wwwroot` folder and `WebView2Loader.dll`. The other .dll files should not be needed.

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi for your comments however I got `0x80070002` error code after doing what you suggest and in the error details it  `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Check whether you have hard-coded some other path. BTW **never** use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or anything `current` when building a path (unless you want to know, at this time - not in the future - what directory is *current*), which **requires** `Path.Combine()` -- BTW2 you have an error, which states it cannot find a file, but you haven't specified what file and, BTW3, I have no idea what you have actually done. -- Use the Project's `Publish` feature of VS 2022, it's quite simplified (given that it uses a dedicated UI) and perfectly working.

Comment: I tried the same example in docs and I got same error

Comment: Still unspecified: 1) What file(s) is (are) missing? 2) If you didn't use the `Publish` feature, did you manually remove `[Project Name].staticwebassets.runtime.json`? 3) If you **did** use the Publish feature, do you have other file references that use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? 3b) Did you build a self-contained executable? 4) What did you actually copy in this other machine? -- Please, update the question with information that covers these points.

Comment: You don't have to copy files from the `wwwroot` folder to the output folder *manually*. You have to select each file and set `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to output directory = Copy if newer`, or do this when you add a new file. -- If you used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` anywhere in your Project, you have to remove it. -- If you use the `Publish` feature, in its applet set the path to `\bin\Publish\ `. It will generate a `Release` build, then copy the required files to the `Publish` folder. You get your files from here (read my previous comment about it).

Comment: Not clear what this: `obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\scopedcss\bundle` has to do with anything here, since you said you followed the example in the documentation you linked. This is unrelated and is part of a folder (`obj`) that has no direct reference in the Project's files. -- If you still cannot run the executable, post the Project somewhere (only the actual content of the Project, no `obj`, `Debug`, `Release` or `Publish` folders)

Comment: Dear @Jimi, It is because I use visual studio 2022 but not the preview version I updated the question and even though I use the visual studio 2022 preview version Version 17.3.0 Preview 2.0 I had same problem

Comment: I've downloaded your Project. It's exactly as the MSDN sample code. Just rebuilt, packaged (as described before), run the self-contained executable in a machine that doesn't have .Net 6 installed (Windows 10 21H1). No problem at all. The only files needed are: the executable, `WebView2Loader.dll` and the content of `wwwroot`. -- Also tested in a Windows 11 machine: same result.

Comment: If you use the same Project you posted, package it as described and it doesn't work on a test machine, the problem is probably the test machine.

Comment: Does the target machine have WebView2 runtime installed? When it's missing, you'll get some "file not found" errors when you try to run an app with a WebView2 control.

Comment: I protect the question because it seems to only attract "Me too" answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the solution to my issue is to install WebView2 on the target machine. I download and install the WebView2 Runtime from:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/consumer/